# Telethon message reply and profile photo download not working

Tags: python, telethon

I copied these codes from the telethon site.
But why does it happen that the profile photo does not land when I use the command ".save" on the person's private page?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
client = TelegramClient('xxx', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=True, pattern=r'\.save'))
async def handler(event):
    if event.is_reply:
        replied = await event.get_reply_message()
        sender = replied.sender
        await client.download_profile_photo(sender)
        await event.respond('Saved your photo {}'.format(sender.username))
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: You should configure `logging` to see what goes wrong inside event handlers. Both Python and Telethon documentation explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `sender.id` as argument in await `client.download_profile_photo`

I use a similar function and it works fine

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=True, pattern=("\+pet")))
async def pet(event): 
    reply = await event.get_reply_message() 
    await event.delete() 
    pic = await client.download_profile_photo(reply.sender_id) 
    petpet.make(pic, "res.gif") 
    await reply.reply(file="res.gif")
```